# Displaying View of MVC in browser that dont have controller or action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-routing

In MVC, I have created a .cshtml file in the path "App/Main/Views".

I dont have any controller or Action for this file. But I need to display the content of .cshtml file in browser.

Please, let me know how I should give route path in 'RouteConfig.cs' file to achieve the above scenario.

Comment: As @Cros states: "If you have no Controller or Action, it shouldn't be a view." Routing is there to provide nice readable URLs, so requires a controller for its routing. If you just want raw files with no brains, just use an HTML file.

Answer (score 1):

Asp.Net MVC is based around Controllers that return views. Your routes point to Actions in Controllers that render Views. What you seem to be looking for is a static view which in this case can be handled as a pure *.html-file instead.

If you have no Controller or Action, it shouldn't be a view.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this configuration

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Main", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

And then in your MainController return that view this way:

```
public class MainController : Controller

        {
            // GET: Main
            public ActionResult Index()
            {

                    return View("MyView", new MyViewModel{ title = "blabla"});
    }
    }
```

Comment: But, I don't have any controller in my application. I just have only view pages. How should I configure to display the view page without controller.